# Reuse data across iterations

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

For testing a POST request to an API, I'm using postman. What I'm trying to achieve is that every request I do selects some data from a big file (randomly) and uses this data to populate the body of the request.

What I would like is that I can select for example 10 iterations and have every one of this iterations pick some random data out of the file I would provide.

I have this working for 1 iteration.

The problem is that in Postman I can't find a way to use the data for the first iteration for all iterations.

A workaround could be to copy-paste the data for every iteration I would like to do, but since this will be a rather large dataset I would like to avoid this.

In short, I'm looking for a way to provide a file to the postman runner and use the data in that file for every iteration I would run.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and call your request in a while function with pm.setNextRequest('nameOfYourRequest');

```
function reccurrentCall(iterations){
   while(iterations !== 0){
   postman.SetNextRequest('nameOfYourRequest');
   iterations--;
};
```

And call the function with number of Iterations you want to make

```
recurrentCall(5);
```

Comment: This will probably work, thanks. Seems like a bit of a hack to me, because if I would like to make the number of iterations easily configurable, I would add them in the data file I provide instead of using the postman UI for this.